# Create a textLabel in Roblox using only code

Tags: user-interface, label, roblox, textlabel

As the title indicates, I am looking at creating a label for a player Gui in Roblox using only code. Under the folder StarterGui, I have a ScreenGui, and as a child of ScreenGui I have a local script with the following code:

```
local ScreenGui = script.Parent
local label = Instance.new("TextLabel", ScreenGui)
label.Size = UDim2.new({0, 200},{0, 100})
label.Text = "label"
label.TextColor3 = Color3.new (0,0,0)
label.TextSize = 36
label.Font =  "Arial"
label.TextScaled = true
```

I am pretty sure I should be seeing a label with the word ''label'' by now,  but nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line that says 
label.Size = UDim2.new({0, 200},{0, 100})

Should be 
label.Size = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 100)

This is because UDim2.new accepts 4 arguments, not 2 arrays.

Hope I could help!